# Hapi v16.x.x: compose multiple route plugins into one

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I currently register my routes using plugins like so:

server.js:

```
const movieRoutes = require('./movies/routes');
server.register([ userRoutes, movieRoutes ], err => {
...
    server.start( err => {
    ...
    });
});
```

movies/routes.js:

```
exports.register = (server,options,next) => {
   server.route(...); // first route
   server.route(...); // second route
}
```

Essentially I am defining all the route handlers in the above movies/route.js

What I'd like to do is to be able to split this into separate files then somehow require them back into `movies/routes.js`. Is there a way to do that?

In pseudocode:

movies/routes.js

```
exports.register = (server,options,next) => {
   // require first route
   // require second route
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because the routes.js is getting pretty long and I'd like to separate them into separate files.

Answer (score 1):

You can export your functions in a file :

```
const fooBar = function() {}

exports.fooBar = fooBar;
```

Then require your handler functions in the file where you declare your routes (in pseudocode).

```
const fooBar = require('fooBar');
exports.register = (server,options,next) => {
  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/path',
    handler: fooBar
  });

  next();
}
```

In the other hand, what I do is that I require a lot of small file containing routes in small batch… I think, it's cleaner

Comment: the caveat is that I depend on the database object that is attached to the server object. how can I include this? as the handler can only take request and reply (version 16)

Comment: You can bind the server to the function: `fooBar.bind(null, server)` but it is starting to be dirty in my own opinion

Comment: I figured it out! I needed `server.app.db`, which is still accessible through the request object as `request.server.app.db`. This allows me to define my functions elsewhere just like in your example, and as I had wanted to! Got inspired to check this out from stumbling on discussions regarding the pre handler.

Comment: well my initial question was under the assumption that I wasn't able to access the server object if I extracted the handlers, which isn't the case as I've found out.